# Extracting Weekly Visitor Data from Google Analytics via API

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on streamlining the process of consolidating visitor data from a specific Google Analytics page. My objective is to compile this data on a weekly basis and present it in a structured table.

For clarity, I've highlighted the specific section of interest in the following screenshot:

[image: Highlighted Google Analytics Section]

The desired table format is envisioned as:

```
 Date       Number of Users
12 AUG         213
13 AUG         200
14 AUG         200
15 AUG         200
...        ...
```

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve this data using the Google Analytics API, rather than manually accessing the web page? I've perused the official API documentation but haven't come across a pertinent example. Any guidance or pointers in this direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to ask a question and hopefully I can get a proper answer.